# Cursor.execute in pymsql isn't execute. Program stop before

Tags: python, mysql, server, dao, pymysql

This is my ConnectionFactory class used by DAO

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
import pymysql
class ConnectionFactory:
    host='127.0.0.1'
    user='nicolacivile'
    password='12345'
    db='ildb'

    connectionFactory = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.connectionFactory  is None:
                cls.connectionFactory  = super().__new__(ConnectionFactory)
                return cls.connectionFactory
        return cls.connectionFactory

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = self.connect()  
    
    def connect(self):
        try:
                return pymysql.connect(host=self.host,
                            user=self.user,
                            password=self.password,
                            db=self.db,
                cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

        except pymysql.Error as e:
                pass

    def getConn(self):
        return self.conn
```

This is class Dao that execute query for return one annotation passing idAnnotationWebServer
my problem is that `cursor.execute(self.SELECT_ANNWEBSERVER_PK_QUERY, (idAnnotationWebServer) )` isn't execute. Program it stop before.

```
from etl_model_connectionfactory import ConnectionFactory
import MySQLdb

class AnnotationWebServerDAO:
    conn = None
    
    errorMessage = ""

    SELECT_ANNWEBSERVER_PK_QUERY = ''' 
    SELECT 
    annotation_web_server_id,
    web_server_id, 
    annotation_code,        
    annotation_name,   
    date_created,   
    date_modified,  
    date_deleted,   
    deleted 
    FROM annotation_web_server 
    WHERE annotation_web_server_id = %s
    AND (deleted = 0 OR deleted IS NULL) '''

    def clearErrorMessage(self):
        self.errorMessage = ""

    def setErrorMessage(self, msg):
        self.errorMessage = msg

    def getErrorMessage(self):
        return self.errorMessage

    def getConnection(self):
        connes=None
        connes=ConnectionFactory()
        return connes.getConn()

    def setConnection(self,connes):
        self.conn = connes

    
    def getAnnWebServer(self,idAnnotationWebServer):
        print('in getAnnWebServer')
        if self.conn is None:
            print("is none self.conn")
            self.conn = self.getConnection()

        self.clearErrorMessage()

        annotation = None

        try:
            print("before cursor")
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            print("after cursor",idAnnotationWebServer)
            cursor.execute(self.SELECT_ANNWEBSERVER_PK_QUERY, (idAnnotationWebServer) )
            print("after execute")
            annotations = cursor.fetchall()
            print("fetch annotations",annotations)

            if(annotations is not None or len(annotations) > 0 ):
                annotation = annotations[0]
            else:
                annotation = None
                msg = "L'annotazione specifica non è presente."
                self.setErrorMessage(msg)

        except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
            annotation = None
            msg = "Error: Could not make connection to the MySQL database"
            self.setErrorMessage(msg)
            print("Error: Could not make connection to the MySQL database")
            print(e)
        
        cursor.close()
        print("exit from getAnnWebServer")
        return annotation
```

I call is this way

```
from etl_model_annotationwebserver_dao import AnnotationWebServerDAO

idAnnotationWebServer = 3
annotationWebServerDao = AnnotationWebServerDAO()
ann = annotationWebServerDao.getAnnWebServer(idAnnotationWebServer)
print("ann",ann)
```

It print this output:

```
idAnnotationWebServer 3
in getAnnWebServer
is none self.conn
before cursor
after cursor 3
```

Can you help me? I don't undestand